# How to make case sensitive query Using ODBC

Tags: mysql, vb.net, authentication, odbc

I am trying to build a web portal thing. I want my password to be case sensitive.

```
Dim params As New ListDictionary()
params.Add("UserName", txtUserName.Text)
params.Add("Password", txtPwd.Text)
Dim Sql = "select * from PortalUsers_bmkzn7zze where UserName =" + 
db.ParameterName("UserName") +
" and  Password = " + db.ParameterName("Password")
'please check the condition 
If db.ExecuteSingletonQuery(Sql, params) Then
```

I am using DBNETsuite as UI layer and qunect as my odbc provider.

I am wondering how will you perform case sensitive query for ODBC. I tired Collateral but that didn't work.

Any help is really appreciated